# How do you rotate an array of strings in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, string, matrix

In Python, given the following array of strings,

```
[   'abc',
    'def',
    'ghi',
    'jkl'
]
```

how do you transform it so it becomes,

```
[   'jgda',
    'kheb',
    'lifc'
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `zip` and `str.join`

**Ex:**

```
a = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl']

for i in zip(*a):
    print("".join(i)[::-1])
```

**Output:**

```
jgda
kheb
lifc
```

- `[::-1]` to reverse the string.

Comment: Or `list(map(''.join, zip(*reversed(lst))))`

Comment: @tobias_k Thanks :)

Comment: yes, certainly reversing the list *first* is an improvement, in your syntax would be `for i in zip(*a[::-1]): print("".join(i))`

Answer (score 1):

You could use numpy

```
import numpy as np
x = ['abc',
     'def',
     'ghi',
     'jkl'
  ]

a = np.rot90([list(row) for row in x], 3)
result = [''.join(row) for row in a]
```

output:

```
[
 'jgda', 
 'kheb', 
 'lifc'
]
```